# AngularJS $scope.$watch on an object's properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to watch a simple object on $scope, but I am confused as to why the following always outputs `state:{value}` for both the country and state select elements.

```
angular.module('app').controller('FiltersCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterRepo', function ($scope, filterRepo) {

    $scope.data = {
        lookups: {
            countries: [
                { id: 1, name: 'USA' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Canada' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Mexico' }
            ],
            states: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Oregon' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Texas' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Iowa' }
            ]
        }
    };

    $scope.query = {
        filter: {
            country: 1,
            state: 1
        }
    };

    for (var item in $scope.query.filter) {
        $scope.$watch('query.filter.' + item, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                console.log(item + ' : ' + newValue);
            }
        }, false);
    }

}]);
```

Comment: You cannot use `item` safely inside the `$watch` callback, as its value will have changed to the last possible key (`state`) when the callback is run.

Comment: fiddle-ized http://jsfiddle.net/E62VE/

Comment: @still_learning So how do I get a reference to the object that has changed?

Comment: @Sam use angular.forEach https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343985/angularjs-scope-watch-on-an-objects-properties#comment37635880_24343985) from @still_learning above, only `Function`s have scope, meaning that the callbacks to your `$watch` statements are using the `item` variable you declared in the"parent" function. However, by the time these $watch callbacks are invoked/called, the `for` loop has already updated their values. There's an item about this in [EffectiveJs](http://effectivejs.com/) ([Item 13](https://github.com/effectivejs/code/tree/master/ch2/item13)).

A great answer is to use the power of function closures via [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Two downsides:

1. Only for `Array`s
2. Only in the latest browsers

Angular provides a very convenient method to address both of these concerns in [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

All this might sound rough :) but have a look at it in action in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E62VE/3/